# Parallel.ForEach stop or break takes too long

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I have list of database connections that only one of them is valid.
my application should connect to them and try to get user information based on input userId.

```
               private string GetDatabaseId(string userId)
               {
                string dbId = string.Empty;
                Parallel.ForEach(dictionaryAllDatabases, (db, state) =>
                    {
                        user = GetUserFromDatabase(db.Key, userId);
                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            //we found user in database.set the db.Id and exit the loop
                            //it takes only 500 milliseconds to hit this line
                            dbId = db.Key;
                            state.Stop();
                            return;
                        }

                    }
                );
               //after about 15 seconds, we reach here
               .....
               }
```

it takes less than 500 milliseconds that it finds the valid database and then I call state.Stop() to exit the loop. but it takes about 15 seconds to exit the loop.

Am I doing something wrong?

thanks

P.S.I got the same result if I use Parallel.For

Comment: Maybe because you're reusing the same database instance and its locking at some point waiting for the previous request to complete ?

Comment: no, all the database are different. my application dose not access to some of them and because of that I use Parallel.For to avoid getting timeout or access error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably waiting for the connections on the other tasks to fail.

Try [setting the connection timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) to say 2 seconds.

Stop does not forcefully stop the other tasks, it just prevents new tasks from starting.
Parallel.ForEach decides how to partition the work among tasks.

A better option would be to use `Connection.OpenAsync` with a cancellation token and use `Task.WaitAny()`.

Comment: thanks Eli, is there anyway that stop other tasks? decrease connection time out is good, but i'm not sure this is the best way.

Comment: You can query the IsStopped property on the state to stop prematurely, but your problem is your other tasks are blocking. I'd use connection.OpenAsync with a cancellation token and use Task.WaitAny instead of Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: @salel cool I'll edit my reply to add this option for posterity.